# pandas reading csv with one row spanning multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

My csv starts out like this:

```
,index,spotify_id,artist_name,track_name,album_name,duration_ms,lyrics,lyrics_bert_embeddings
0,0,5Jk0vfT81ltt2rYyrWDzZ5,Hundred Waters,Xtalk - Kodak to Graph Remix,The Moon Rang Like a Bell,285327,not fetched,"[ 0.00722605 -0.23726921  0.15163635 -0.28774077  0.07081255  0.26606813
```

each row ends like this in a new line:

```
  0.03439684 -0.29289168  0.13590978  0.2332756  -0.24305075  0.2034984 ]"
```

These values are from a big numpy array encoded with `np.array2string()` and span multiple lines in the csv.

When using `pd.read_csv` it throws an `"ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 90607".` When using the parameter `engine="python"` it throws an `"ParserError: unexpected end of data"`. When using the seperator sep=`'\t+'` it just puts each line in a new row in the dataframe. When using `csv.reader` by using `with open(file_path)` and then iterating through each line, the same happens as with the `sep='\t+'`.

Is there a way to automatically append each row to the original row it belongs to or do I have to preprocess this by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your csv data to check it. I pasted the code along with the answer below,

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data_path = 'dt.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(data_path, header = None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='utf-8')
dt_json = pd.DataFrame.to_json(df)
print(dt_json)
```

For an example, I just tried to change the data format from CSV to JSON using pandas dataframe.

```
{"0":{"0":null,"1":0.0},
      "1":{"0":"index","1":"0"},
      "2":{"0":"spotify_id","1":"5Jk0vfT81ltt2rYyrWDzZ5"},
      "3":{"0":"artist_name","1":"Hundred Waters"},
      "4":{"0":"track_name","1":"Xtalk - Kodak to Graph Remix"},
      "5":{"0":"album_name","1":"The Moon Rang Like a Bell"},
      "6":{"0":"duration_ms","1":"285327"},
      "7":{"0":"lyrics","1":"not fetched"},
      "8":{"0":"lyrics_bert_embeddings","1":"[ 0.00722605 -0.23726921  0.15163635 -0.28774077  0.07081255  0.26606813\r\n 0.03439684 -0.29289168  0.13590978  0.2332756  -0.24305075  0.2034984 ]"}}
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv

Comment: this didnt work and it threw the same error but i regenerated the csv by using str() instead of array2string(), then I converted the str back to numpy using [np.fromstring(x.replace('\n','').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('  ',' '), sep=' ') for x in lyrics_df.lyrics_bert_embeddings] (this can take up to a minute for my csv with almost 2 million rows)